# GWT: Response not coming back to onSubmitComplete when sending csv file in response

Tags: gwt, csv, download, httpresponse

I am trying to get the response back from the servlet which is essentially a ".csv" file.
I upload a file to the server parse it read it and then if there are any errors in the file I write it into CSV file and send it back in response. But it seems that the response never come back to onSubmitComplete.
Here is my code.

```
if (!errorContents.isEmpty()) {

                            CSVWriter csv = null;
                            try{
                                String filename = "errorList.csv";
                                resp.setContentType("text/plain");
                                resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
                                csv = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(resp.getOutputStream()));

                                for (String[] row : errorContents) {
                                    csv.writeNext(row);
                                }

                            }finally {
                                csv.close();
                            }

                        } else {
                            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
                            resp.getWriter().write("Successful Processing");

                        }
```

now the code at client controller

```
formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSubmitComplete(FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
                controller.reloadAll();
                com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.alert(event.getResults().toString());
                hideContentDiv();
//                loading.hide();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Many browsers will only fire the event if text/html comes back.
This a known quirk, and is documented http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html#FormPanel()

Comment: I have used text/html also application/csv.
But nothing seems to work. The response is not getting back to the page. Actually it does. The error file gets downloaded at the client side but I have reload the page to see the changes after the file gets to the client side.

Comment: I was doing to much thinking. I did solve the problem entirely other way so working fine for me.- Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RohanDmello could you please share your solution?